# Is there a way to halt a GPU thread until all threads being executed reach that point?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, gpu, hlsl, cellular-automata

I am currently working on a compute shader that does CA-based fluid simulation. My current algorithm writes to the direct neighbours of the cell currently being computed. My current idea is to have one thread compute a 3x3 area of my CA grid, and subsequently, each 3x3 area adjacent to the other. This in theory would ensure that a pixel that is being written to would not be prematurely read.

I need some way to prevent a thread from continuing until all other threads have reached the same point.

Pseudo Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i+) {
    // do all calculations necessary

    while(true) {
       if (allThreadsDone)
            break;
    }
}
```

This may not be necessary though if the computation of each thread was constant time, which I do not know if is true.

Comment: Would you be able to rewrite it in some way that it would only write to its own cell? Synchronization heavily threaded applications is not efficient and often just nightmares. Often it's easier and faster to have a wasteful algorithm but not requiring any synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked more into it and it appears that there is no way to halt GPU threads. I have also been told that threads end all at the same time if they have a constant number of instructions.

Comment: This is both not fully true, but also not fully wrong. For one, there is a way to halt GPU threads: ``AllMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync ()``. But it only halts until all threads *in that group* reach that point, not ALL threads you dispatch. Also, all threads *within a wave front* will execute at the same time, since they're running on the same SIMD processor. However, threads on two different wave fronts will not exeucte at the same time - depending on what you do in your shader, it's not even guaranteed whether they take approx. the same time, even with constant number of instructions.